# How to Totalize all the score with Sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

As i know the basic of save int value with sharedpreferences method is using this

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("savedscore", Score);
    editor.commit();
```

and then we can get the int value in another activity using this

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Score = pref.getInt("savedscore", 0);
Scoretext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textscore);
Scoretext.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

and my question is how to totalize all the score that we got when we playing in another activity?

example ;

when i play for the first time i got the score 4000 , so of course when we use this method `editor.putInt("savedscore", Score);` it will save the score value and then we got the score value in another activity with using this `Score = pref.getInt("savedscore", 0);` it will make the int Score value to 4000

and then i play again then i got score 2000 , so of course the sharedpreferences `Score = pref.getInt("savedscore", 0);` int Score value will change to 2000 and not totalize

so that is my question how to Totalize the score?

Comment: you mean, like summing two int values before storing the sum ?

Comment: yes, but i mean is all the time score that we got when playing is totalize

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but maybe what you are looking for is `Score += newScore;` ?

Comment: yes tight, like that

Answer (score 1):

Simply create another preference entry "*totalScore*" and increment it accordingly (each time you save a new score):

```
//...
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putInt("savedscore", Score);
editor.commit();
updateTotalScore(Score)
//..


private void updateTotalScore(int newScore){
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("totalScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
   int current = pref.getInt("totalScore", 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
   editor.putInt("totalScore", current+newScore);
   editor.commit();
}


private int getTotalScore(){
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("totalScore", MODE_PRIVATE);
   return pref.getInt("totalScore", 0);

}
```

Comment: but how if i getInt("totalScore", 0); in another activity?

Comment: @Archanister SharedPref does not depends on Activities (it is process-dependent when using MODE_PRIVATE), so you will get the same result

Comment: hy bonnyz the method not working good when it open twice, can we make some chat room so i can tell the problem more detail?

Comment: @Archanister please explain your problem, I'll update my answer accordingly